# Debugging SVG performance on IE 10

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, svg, svg-animate

I have a pretty complicated SVG doc I'm displaying on IE 10. It's stretched to the full size of the viewport and uses the `viewBox` attribute. I'm noticing that transforming layers in the doc is EXTREMELY slow (like, 1fps slow). This does not happen in other desktop browsers.

Aside from JS profiling using F12, anyone have ideas on other tools available for IE10 that would be relevant to figure out what's slowing down my transformations?

Comment: Did you mean `viewBox` attribute?

Comment: Could you add an example to the question?